# Undeclared identifier error in C for loop?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, sizeof

I am new to C, and I am writing a program to compute a "double-pass" variance calculation for a small dataset. The value I'm getting is completely wrong, and I think it's a specific for loop (below) that's the source of the issue.

```
float sum_v_f_double = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i <= size_f; i++)
    sum_v_f_double += (arr_f[i-1]-mean_f)*(arr_f[i-1]-mean_f);
```

If I simply try to print the value of this calculation, it only prints it once.

Input:

```
float sum_v_f_double = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i <= size_f; i++)
    sum_v_f_double += (arr_f[i-1]-mean_f)*(arr_f[i-1]-mean_f);
    printf("%f\n", sum_v_f_double);
```

Output:

```
672057216.000000
```

This is obviously a problem, and idicates that it's not even iterating. I have no clue why, since I have a loop above it of the exact same syntax and it works fine. Full program below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    float arr_f[5] = {25924.12, 25924.15, 25923.98, 25924.19, 25923.89};
    /* single precision */
    /* double pass */
    float size_f = sizeof(arr_f)/sizeof(*arr_f);
    float sum_f = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size_f; i++)
        sum_f += arr_f[i-1];
    
    float mean_f = sum_f/size_f;

    float sum_v_f_double = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size_f; i++)
        sum_v_f_double += (arr_f[i-1]-mean_f)*(arr_f[i-1]-mean_f);
        printf("%f\n", sum_v_f_double);

    float var_f_double = (1./(size_f-1.))*sum_v_f_double;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indentation is completely irrelevant to a C compiler. Use `{}` to delimit blocks.

Comment: `i <= size_f` you probably meant `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: If you want to include more than one statement in a `for` loop you need braces. `for(...) { /* as much code as you like */ }`.

Comment: whoa!  Never declare an index/limit as a float.

Comment: Also, starting the loop from 0 and accessing `arr_f[i-1]` is asking for trouble, since element at index -1 doesn't exist.

Comment: Isn't i updated to 1 before the loop starts? Or does i++ occur only after the iteration?

Comment: @lcleary You can read about `for` loops [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for)

Comment: @lcleary Put a `printf("i=%d\n", i);` at the top of the loop to see the values that are assigned to `i` in the loop body.

Answer (score 2):

If you will correctly format this code snippet

```
float sum_v_f_double = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i <= size_f; i++)
    sum_v_f_double += (arr_f[i-1]-mean_f)*(arr_f[i-1]-mean_f);
    printf("%f\n", sum_v_f_double);
```

then you will see that it looks like

```
float sum_v_f_double = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i <= size_f; i++)
    sum_v_f_double += (arr_f[i-1]-mean_f)*(arr_f[i-1]-mean_f);

printf("%f\n", sum_v_f_double);
```

That is the for loop has only the sub-statement

```
sum_v_f_double += (arr_f[i-1]-mean_f)*(arr_f[i-1]-mean_f);
```

If you want that the call of printf would be within the loop you need use the compound statement like

```
float sum_v_f_double = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i <= size_f; i++)
{
    sum_v_f_double += (arr_f[i-1]-mean_f)*(arr_f[i-1]-mean_f);
    printf("%f\n", sum_v_f_double);
}
```

Pay attention to that this for loop invokes undefined behavior due to accessing memory beyond the array when i is equal to 0 in this expression `arr_f[i-1]`.

You should write it at least like

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size_f; i++)
```

Though it is unclear why you are using the expression `arr_f[i-1]` instead of `arr_f[i]` and not using the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < size_f; i++)
```

Also the same problem exists in this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= size_f; i++)
    sum_f += arr_f[i-1];
```

Instead you have to write

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size_f; i++)
    sum_f += arr_f[i-1];
```

Pay attention to that instead of the type float in this declaration

```
float size_f = sizeof(arr_f)/sizeof(*arr_f);
```

you should use an unsigned integer type for example `size_t`. It is the type of a value returned by the operator `sizeof`.

```
size_t size_f = sizeof(arr_f)/sizeof(*arr_f);
```

Comment: Isn't i updated to 1 before the loop starts? Or does i++ occur only after the iteration?

Comment: The update occurs after the for-loop.